# Colors Disappeared on project when import TMP Essentials on Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

help ! On Unity, I got the error

> "Failed to import package with error : couldn't decompress package"

when trying to import TMP Essentials. So I went in the package manager and saw there was an update of the package. I did the update and imported the package to my project but at that moment all colors disappeared from it. All GameObjects appear to be grey and the materials in the assets are all grey too. I also receive a bunch of different and very weird errors:

> -Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 3.5.0-dev-20359-01 (8da8ba0c) Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved

> -Assertion failed on expression:"res"

> -Could not load Packages/com.unity.timeline/Editor/StyleSheets/Extensions/common.uss

> -Unknown error occured while loading 'Library/Artifacts/a4/a4a00b281be5cec61a33c9289e6f8db3'

> -Could not load Packages/com.unity.timeline/Editor/StyleSheets/Extensions/light.uss

[the project without colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXHJj.png)

Any advice is welcome for solving this issue, thx.

Comment: Try to make full reimport of the project. You can do it by right-clicking in the project section of the unity editor, or by manually deleting Library and Temp folders

Comment: Unlike DirectX and OpenGL/ES which treat _backwards compatibility_ as first-class citizens, Unity is more like XNA and any updates are likely to break your code.  Including 3rd party asset store/packages.  For this reason prior to any updates, you should commit your current project to source control.  Good luck!